# Java ActionListener not responding

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, inner-classes

hello all been using this site for ages as a lurker but come across this problem and cant find the solution Anywhere...

i have actionlistener in a inner class that just wont respond... any chance you guys could look over my beginner coding and see what you think?

sorry theres so much code here the only bit im having trouble with is the 'AddPet' class and its inner class 'AddEle' and the System.exit method. When the window 'choose pet type dialog' opens nither of these buttons will work... hope i have all the terminology right as im totally self taught and just starting out.

thanks for your time

eddy

```
package petshopwk1;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.* ;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane ;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JList;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class CurrentPet2 extends JFrame {
private JButton setName, setDOB, setSold, getName, getDOB, getSold, addPet, changePre,           changeNext, exit, setCurrentPet, getFeel;
private JLabel cPetLabel ;

private Shop theShop = new Shop("Brighton");

private JButton exitButton, Ele, MF, Pet;
String temp = "temp" ;


Date dob = new Date();
public Pet CurrentPetObj = new Pet("", "", true, dob) ;

int cPetIndex ;


DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
public JList list = new JList(model);


public CurrentPet2 (String cTitle)
            {
super(cTitle) ; 






Pet Alburt = new Pet("Alburt", " 09 APRIL 2009", true) ;
Pet Eddy = new Pet("Eddy", " 13 JANUARY 1982", false) ;
Pet Paul = new Pet("Paul", " 21 DECEMBER 1956", true) ;
Pet Sian = new Pet("Sian", " 11 SEPTEMBER 1988", true) ;
Pet Morrise = new Pet("Morrise", " 26 MARCH 1996", false) ;
Pet Betty = new Pet("Betty", " 31 JANUARY 1962", false) ;
Elephant Ele = new Elephant ("Ele", "13 JANUARY 1982", true, 12) ;
MF NOW = new MF ("NOW", "8 JULY 2012", false, 11, "Rocking") ;


theShop.addPet(0, Alburt);
theShop.addPet(1, Eddy);
theShop.addPet(2, Paul);
theShop.addPet(3, Sian);
theShop.addPet(4, Morrise);
theShop.addPet(5, Betty); 
theShop.addPet(6, Ele);
theShop.addPet(7, NOW);


Container contentPane ;
contentPane = getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());



cPetLabel = new JLabel("Current Pet Mode");

setCurrentPet = new JButton("Choose current Pet");
setName = new JButton("Set Name") ;
setDOB = new JButton("Set DOB") ;
setSold = new JButton("Set Sold");
getName = new JButton("Get Name") ;
getDOB = new JButton("Get DOB") ;
getSold = new JButton("Get Sold") ;
addPet = new JButton("Add Pet");
changePre = new JButton("Change to Previous") ;
changeNext = new JButton("Change to Next");
getFeel = new JButton("FEEL?");
exit = new JButton("EXIT");

exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
{System.exit(0); }}
);



setCurrentPet.addActionListener(new ChoosePetName());
setName.addActionListener(new       setPetName()) ;
setDOB.addActionListener(new        setPetDOB());
setSold.addActionListener(new       setIsSold());
getName.addActionListener(new       getPetName()) ;
getDOB.addActionListener(new        getPetDOB());
getSold.addActionListener(new       getIsSold());
addPet.addActionListener(new        addPet());
getFeel.addActionListener(new       printFeel());

list.setListData(Shop.thePets.toArray());

list.validate();

changePre.addActionListener(new     changePetPre());
changeNext.addActionListener(new    changePetNext());


contentPane.add(setCurrentPet);
contentPane.add(addPet);
contentPane.add(setName);
contentPane.add(setDOB);
contentPane.add(setSold);
contentPane.add(getName);
contentPane.add(getDOB);
contentPane.add(getSold);
contentPane.add(getFeel) ;

contentPane.add(changePre);

contentPane.add(changeNext);
contentPane.add(exit);
contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(list));


list.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
{
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt)
{
JList list = (JList) evt.getSource();
if (evt.getClickCount() ==2 )
{
int cPetIndex = list.locationToIndex (evt.getPoint());
CurrentPetObj = Shop.thePets.get(cPetIndex) ;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this,               CurrentPetObj + "@ Index " + cPetIndex);
}
}
} 
                                                         );

setLayout(new FlowLayout());
add(exit);



this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
this.setSize(550, 400);
this.setVisible(true);

}



class ChoosePetName implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

String cPetSearch  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Eneter Pet to work on...") ;

 CurrentPetObj = Shop.findPet(cPetSearch) ;

 int cPetIndex = Shop.thePets.indexOf(CurrentPetObj);
 list.setSelectedIndex(cPetIndex);

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this, CurrentPetObj + "@ Index " + cPetIndex); 

 }
 }


class setPetName implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
{
String nName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input new Pet name...");

CurrentPetObj.setName(nName);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this, CurrentPetObj) ;


}
}

class setPetDOB implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
String nDOB = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input new Pet DOB... (in format 26 MARCH 1996");
CurrentPetObj.setDOB(nDOB) ;
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this, CurrentPetObj);
}
}

class setIsSold implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
boolean s = Boolean.parseBoolean(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input if new Pet is sold..."));
CurrentPetObj.setIsSold(s);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this, CurrentPetObj.toString());
}
}



class getPetName implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this, CurrentPetObj.getName());

}
}

class getPetDOB implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this, CurrentPetObj.getDOB()) ;
}
}

class getIsSold implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this, CurrentPetObj.getIsSold());
}
}

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    its just between this and the following line i have the problem. the actionListener responds fine in the earlier class but just cant get it working with the AddPet class and therefore wont call the system.exit or AddEle...
```

any help would be great:)

```
***class AddPet implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
Container contentPane ;
contentPane = getContentPane();
contentPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

JFrame f = new JFrame("Choose pet type dialog");
f.setSize(300, 100);
Container content = f.getContentPane();


Ele = new JButton("Add Elephant");
exitButton = new JButton("EXIT");


exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent L )
{System.exit(0); }}
                             );

Ele.addActionListener(new        AddEle());

content.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
content.add(new JButton("Add Elephant"));
content.add(new JButton("Add Pet"));
content.add(new JButton("EXIT"));

contentPane.add(Ele);
contentPane.add(exit);

f.setVisible(true);


contentPane.add(MF);
contentPane.add(Pet);
}
}


class AddEle implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent L )
{

String nName  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please Enter new Pet name...") ;
String nDate  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input new pet DOB (in format 20 MARCH 2001");

boolean s     = Boolean.parseBoolean(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input if     sold or not? ( true / false"));

int nSize = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input Elephant SIZE..."));

cPetIndex = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please input INDEX to place new Pet..."));

Pet CurrentPetObj = new Elephant(nName, nDate, s, nSize) ;
theShop.addPet(cPetIndex, CurrentPetObj) ;
list.setListData(Shop.thePets.toArray());
model.setElementAt(CurrentPetObj, cPetIndex);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this, CurrentPetObj + " @ Index " + cPetIndex); 



}

}

}***
```

---

```
class changePetPre implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
{
int cPetIndex = Shop.thePets.indexOf(CurrentPetObj);

--cPetIndex;
CurrentPetObj = Shop.thePets.get(cPetIndex);
list.setSelectedIndex(cPetIndex);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this, "Current Pet is now == " + CurrentPetObj + "@ Index " + cPetIndex); 

}
}

class changePetNext implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
{
int cPetIndex = Shop.thePets.indexOf(CurrentPetObj);
++cPetIndex;
CurrentPetObj = Shop.thePets.get(cPetIndex);
list.setSelectedIndex(cPetIndex);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this, "Current Pet is now == " + CurrentPetObj   + "@ Index " + cPetIndex); 

}
}

class printFeel implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e )
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CurrentPet2.this, "Current feel is now == " + MF.getFeel()); 
}
}


}
```

Comment: Please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: which part isn't working? (what button, etc)

Comment: it all works appart from the middle window, the class AddPet opens but none of the buttons (Exit, Ele for eg) will work, so it wont call AddEle class... i have a feeling for some reason the action listener cant be used this way / im doing something wrong...

Comment: this question probably isn't possible answering without posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), good luck

Comment: 1) `JFrame f = new JFrame("Choose pet type dialog");`  No, it is not a dialog, it is a frame, and does not behave in the same way a users would expect a dialog to work.  See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  2) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the action listeners to buttons you don't add to the frame (the ones you *do* add are new instances, and don't have the action listeners)

Try:

```
content.add(Ele); 
content.add(exitButton);
```

in `AddPet`

Comment: Thanks Attila! managed to figure it out from that, looks like i need to revise to difference and or interaction between the JFrame and the Container, ended up just a case of bad naming i think... thanks all:)